# Why this Notice Error?

Tags: php

here is my code and its working

```
<?php
        $num = 5;
        $location = 'tree';
        define(format,'There are %d monkeys in the %s');
        echo sprintf(format, $num, $location);
        ?>
```

but i'm getting

> **NOTICE** Use of undefined constant format - assumed 'format' on line number 6
>
> There are 5 monkeys in the tree

Why?

Comment: You used `format` as a constant instead of string. Use as `define('format', 'There are %d monkeys in the %s');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `'`s to avoid the **Notice**

```
define('format','There are %d monkeys in the %s');
```

Standard constant names are in capital letters. You should do -

```
define('FORMAT','There are %d monkeys in the %s');
```

[define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert '' while defining a variable

```
<?php

 $num = 5;
 $location = 'tree';
 define('format','There are %d monkeys in the %s');
 echo sprintf(format, $num, $location);

?>
```